# jquery focus not working on blur

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to keep the focus on a text box on blur if validation fails. But Its working in IE but not working FF. Any suggestions?

```
$("#inputBoxId").blur(function () {
   if ($(this).val() < 10) 
      $("#inputBoxId").focus();

});
```

Comment: Guys, i"ve problem with the .focus(). Its not getting focus after meeting condition also..no problem in the condition!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you need to use setTimeout according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097905/keep-focus-on-blur-event).  Since you are giving focus to an element immediately you need to account for some time for the element to go out of focus first.

```
$("#inputBoxId").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() < 10) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#inputBoxId").focus();
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

Example of it working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/XhV2h/1/), tested out on chrome dev channel, firefox, and IE8.

Comment: Seems like an FF issue only. Also 0 would work instead of 100 as well.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely has saved time

Answer (score 1):

`val()` will return string, not number. Try converting and it should work:

```
var value = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
if (isNaN(value) || value < 10) 
      $("#inputBoxId").focus();
```

This will also deal with non numeric values.

Comment: I don't think this will make a difference as type coercion happens anyway when a string is compared to a number. Although `"" < 10 === true`, so maybe it will make a difference ;)

Comment: @Box9 maybe older versions of FF won't do the type conversion by themselves.. ?

Comment: the problem was not with the type..it was with the focus event..solved now :)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).val().length` will also give the length

```
$("#inputBoxId").blur(function () {
    if($(this).val().length < 10 ){
          $(this).focus();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// Page visibility :

```
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {

        if (document.hidden) {
            // stop running expensive task

        } else {
            // page has focus, begin running task

        }
    });
```