# Datepicker max value not being validated

Tags: jquery, html

I have a datepicker with maxdate set as today. Here is how I defined it:

```
$('selector').datepicker({
yearRange: "c-100:+0",
maxDate: '+0d',
changeMonth : true,
changeYear : true,
showAnim:"fold"
});
```

The **maxDate** property works fine when the user selects from the **datepicker ui**. It shows all the future dates as disabled; however, datepicker allows the user to enter a date via the keyboard as well which is where the problem begins.

DatePicker even validates the value of manually entered text when the user presses **enter** (submits the form) but does not validate it when it is **blurred** and then the form is submitted; i.e., when the user comes out of the input box without pressing **enter**. This allows the date to be greater than the maximum date and can be submitted without showing an error.

I can make the text input read-only, but in that case user can not input the date via keyboard.

Since I am new to jquery, am I missing some property that would validate on blur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to validate the Date Picker field to be a date in the past and that validation isn't happening when the user is leaving the field. I'm not familiar enough with Date Picker to say that there is a validation method that you could specifically call when the user leaves the field with a date in the future, but you could fairly easily write your own validation routine for when the user leaves focus out of the Date Picker field.

Tested:

```
$("selector").blur(function(e) {
    var today = new Date();
    if ( $(this).datepicker("getDate") > today ) {
        alert("Incorrect");
        // Here you could force their field to be equal to 
        // today if you would like or handle it otherwise
    }
});
```

You could also validate the field on submit.

**However**, even with all these lovely protections in place, you *cannot substitute* these for validating on the server side. You should validate and provide proper error messages in the event the user circumvents the Javascript protections and submits the form with a date in the future. Hope that helps you.

**Update**: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1097985/469643) is a really interesting discussion about blur and focus in case you want to lock down the behavior of leaving the field with a future value. It may or may not be applicable to what you want to do/use.

Another thought is that in your error message, you might want to be as descriptive as possible in the types of date that should be input (YYYY-mm-dd) so users from different perspectives (mm/dd/yy or whatever) know why their input is getting rejected.

Comment: yeah I will validate the value of the date in server side as well.Well thanks for the advice thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a bug in jquery datepicker. You will have to write your own validation for textbox as mentioned by veeTrain. Or take a look at this if you want something readymade. http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html

Comment: Nice find on the plugin; have you used it?

Comment: I haven't used it in a project but tested it on the website.