# Keeping a textarea always focused

Tags: javascript, html

Which is the best way to keep a textarea always focused?

`<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>`

var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

this:

```
  textarea.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    textarea.focus();
  });
```

or this:

```
textarea.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    textarea.focus();
  }, 0);
});
```

Don't tell about `autofocus` attribute.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the user from clicking on another element and having the textarea lose focus? Or make the textarea gain focus on an event like page load?

Comment: say the textarea is wrapped in the whole page. it shouldn't be blurred by `alert()` or `prompt()`

Comment: Not possible, `alert()` and `pronpt()` are modal windows, which will capture focus in any case. You can use custom alert/prompt though.

Comment: @Teemu yea I know. but I don't want to prevent them doig so...
I want to gain the focus back to `textarea`

Comment: The keyword is _modal_, a modal window won't let you do anything elsewhere, before it has been closed. Btw, what's the idea of showing `prompt()`, if user can't enter text to it?

Comment: Maybe take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097905/keep-focus-on-blur-event

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code you're looking for:

```
var textarea = $('textarea');

textarea.bind("blur", function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
    textarea.focus();
  }, 0);
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lxpcqeeeee

Comment: Can I learn why did you use `setTimeout()` function there?